# Cannot understand why function will not work

Tags: c++, function

The goal of this program is to input a base followed by any number of spaces and then a sequence of characters, any number as long as they are 1 less than the base. I have the errors covered, but I cannot get it to display.

If I input 2      1101, my output is For the given base 2, "Nothing appears".

```
The output should be the following: Test Case # 1
Input for Run 1:
2      1101
3    1212
5   66
2   1111
8   36
2 01

The output for Test Run 1: 
For the given base 2, the decimal value of the input string is 11.
For the given base 3, the decimal value of the input string is 70.
For the given base 5, the number is NOT valid!
For the given base 2, the decimal value of the input string is 15.
For the given base 8, the decimal value of the input string is 51.
For the given base 2, the decimal value of the input string is 2.
```

Here is my coding for this section of the program I have issues with:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_CHARS = 256;
const int MAX_BASE = 10;

int readUntiValidBaseRead();
int readNumbersReturningValue( int base );
int decimalValueOf( char chDigit );
bool isValid( char chDigit, int base );

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function reads bases until a valid base is read or eof occurs.
// If an invalid base is read, an error message is displayed and the 
// rest of the line is ignored and another attempt to read a base value
// will be attempted.
// -1 is returned if eof occurs otherwise a valid base value is 
// returned.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int readUntilValidBaseRead()
{
   int readingBase;
   cin >> readingBase;
   while( !cin.eof() && (readingBase < 1 || readingBase > MAX_BASE))
   {
      cout << "Invalid base given, " << endl;
      cin.ignore(MAX_CHARS, '\n');
      cin >> readingBase;
   }
   if(readingBase > 1 && readingBase <= MAX_BASE)
      return readingBase;
   else
      return -1;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function reads in a sequence of characters that represent
// a number in the given base.  A valid sequence is given in a 
// "backwards" format such that the rightmost digit is given first,
// the second to the rightmost digit is next, etc. 
// This function returns the value of this sequence of characters if
// it is a valid sequence.  If it is not valid it returns -1. 
// params: base -> IN
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int readNumbersReturningValue( int base )
{
   char readingNumber;
   int sum = 0;
   int theValue = 1;
   bool flaq = true;
   cin >> readingNumber;
   while(readingNumber != '\n' && flaq)
   {
      flaq = isValid(readingNumber, base);
      sum += (theValue* decimalValueOf(readingNumber));
      theValue *= base;
      cin >> readingNumber;
      flaq = isValid(readingNumber, base);
   }
   if(flaq == true)
      return sum;
   else
      return -1;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function returns the numeric value of the character digit that
// is stored in chDigit.
// params: chDigit -> IN
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
int decimalValueOf( char chDigit )
{
   int decimalNum;
   decimalNum = chDigit - '0';
   return decimalNum; //return integer value of 
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function returns true if chDigit is a valid digit in the given
// base, it returns false otherwise.
// params: chDigit -> IN, base -> IN
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
bool isValid( char chDigit, int base )
{
   if(decimalValueOf(chDigit) >= 0 && decimalValueOf(chDigit) < base)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//
//
int main()
{
   int totalSum = 0;
   int base;
   int singleSum;

   base = readUntilValidBaseRead();
   while(!cin.eof())
   {

      cout << "For the given base " << base << ", ";
      singleSum = readNumbersReturningValue(base);

      if(singleSum == -1)
      {
         cout << "Not valid. Throwing away rest of line. " << endl;
         cin.ignore(MAX_CHARS, '\n');
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "The decimal value of the input string is " << singleSum;
         totalSum += singleSum;
      }
      base = readUntilValidBaseRead();
   }
   cout << totalSum;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing half your functions. If you want help on a particular function, please construct a complete and compilable example that only uses that function. Chances are good that if you do this, you'll find your problem by yourself, but if not, post something that we can compile and look into.

Comment: Do you have something against `std:string`?

Comment: Print out the value of `base`. Are you sure that's `readUntilValidBaseRead` is ok?

Comment: I think you need to be using `std::getline` then split the string by spaces and parse the two halves into numbers and do whatever else.. It doesn't make sense to while loop until `'\n'`.

Comment: Cannot use strings, only chars allowed. I'm doing this for a program that we aren't to use strings whatsoever.

Comment: How can it print "Nothing appears" since that doesn't even appear in the code?  If you mean that nothing is printed (neither of the specified cout lines are printed) is that because the program terminates unexpectedly so the cout buffer doesn't get cleared?  It could do that because you have the endl on the "Not valid..." cout but not on the "The decimal value..." cout.

Comment: The program is still running...I also added an endl to it and nothing changes, it simply gets to the "Nothing appears" and yes I meant that literally nothing happens, the program still runs and allows for an input but Its not outputting what I need it to.

Comment: Your `isValid()` function will return `false` for spaces.

Comment: How do I skip the spaces in my invalid() ?

Comment: Like: http://ideone.com/OUIQql You don't even need to worry about spaces like that.. It does it for you.. Just make sure to loop it and check whether the value stored in "base" and "value" is valid..

Comment: I've had about a month and a half of c++ experience...I really have no idea what your website means and @PaulGriffiths , I don't know how to fix my issue there. The check for isvalid checks it right away.. doesn't it?

Comment: @user2108147: Then change it so that it doesn't check it right away. It's your program, you're allowed to change it to make it work.

Comment: I have it narrowed down to the ReadNumbersReturningValue(int base). Something in there is not allowing the sum to be displayed.

Comment: Vague title does not contribute to the value of this site. Future visitors with the same problem will not be able to find this question because the title says nothing about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
cin >> readingNumber;
while(readingNumber != '\n' && flaq)
{
    flaq = isValid(readingNumber, base);
    sum += (theValue* decimalValueOf(readingNumber));
    theValue *= base;
    cin >> readingNumber;
    flaq = isValid(readingNumber, base);
}
```

you increment `sum` on the first read, regardless of whether or not the character read is valid. And it never will be valid, since your `isValid()` function returns `false` for spaces. You should skip over any spaces, and only then start checking for digits. You don't need to worry about spaces when you read into an `int`, but you do when you're reading into a `char`, because whitespace characters are characters, and `cin` doesn't know whether or not you want to skip them.

You can skip them with something like:

```
do {
    cin >> readingNumber;
} while ( isspace(readingNumber) );
```

You'll need to `#include <cctype>` for `isspace()`. Note this will skip any whitespace character, including tabs and newlines, so you might want to check for `\n` individually if you might have completely missing input.

Here's a working example, just for the skipping the spaces and reading your numbers (i.e. ignoring reading the base):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int decimalValueOf(char chDigit) {
   return chDigit - '0';
}

bool isValid(char chDigit, int base) {
   return (decimalValueOf(chDigit) >= 0 && decimalValueOf(chDigit) < base );
}

int readNumbersReturningValue(int base) {
    char readingNumber;
    int sum = 0;
    int theValue = 1;
    bool flaq = true;

    do {
        std::cin >> readingNumber;
    } while ( std::isspace(readingNumber) );

    while ( readingNumber != '\n' && (flaq = isValid(readingNumber, base)) ) {
        sum += (theValue* decimalValueOf(readingNumber));
        theValue *= base;
        readingNumber = std::cin.get();
    }

    if ( flaq ) {
        return sum;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum = readNumbersReturningValue(2);
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$ ./readchars
             1101
Sum is: 11
paul@local:~/src/cpp/scratch$
```

Note that `std::cin >> readingNumber;` won't work for picking up newlines, since `std::cin` is line buffered, so you have to use `std::cin.get()` instead.

Comment: I did that, the output still just stops and will not output anything after my "Nothing appears" statement above in the description.

Comment: @user2108147: Because what you're doing won't work for reading newlines, so it's always hanging. See my edit.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate it. I saw that 

while(readingNumber == ' ')
readingNumber = cin.get()

also worked. Thank you so much for all the help. It really is a pain only having a month and a half under my belt. If I may ask, where did you learn all this? Just through experience and being on this website, mind sharing a few tips with the rookie?

Comment: I just learned it from doing it for a long time and picking things up. There weren't any websites when I started this stuff, but we had books and things.